# How to get content from span with Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using Jsoup HTML parser to extract content from a HTML page.

```
<span class="mainPrice reduced_">
<span class="oPrice" data-test="preisArtikel">
<span itemprop="price" content="68.00"><span class="oPriceLeft">68</span><span             class="oPriceSeparator">,</span><span class="oPriceRight">00</span></span><span      class="oPriceSymbol oPriceSymbolRight">&euro;</span>
```

I want to extract the content (68.00) and I tried following:

```
Elements price = doc.select("span.oPrice");
String priceString = price.text();
```

That doesn't work because the class "oPrice" occurs 44 times in the page and the string "priceString" contains 44 different prices.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
     //For one element
   Element elements = document.select("span[content]").first();
        System.out.println(elements.attr("content"));
```

If you have multiple like same span

```
   //For multiple
  Elements elements = document.select("span[content]");
    for (Element element:elements){
        System.out.println(element.attr("content"));
    }
```

Output:
68.00

On top of that Check [JsoupSelector](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html) for the reference.